# How can I connect to Hotmail/Live Mail/Outlook on iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, email, hotmail

I want to connect to a user's inbox to view their messages.

I've tried using the open source project MailCore, which has helped me to access Gmail without problem, but it turns out that Hotmail doesn't support IMAP, and MailCore doesn't support POP3. As far as I understand it, SMTP is only for outgoing mail, and so I can't connect to the Inbox to access messages using this.

Setting up hotmail in the default mail app on iOS is a breeze, however.

Any ideas on how I can connect to Hotmail in my app?

Comment: MailCore2, of course!

Comment: Wow, this actually exists. Thanks!